# SwfitUI navigationBarItems calls location permission twice

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, uinavigationbar, swiftui

I created a button under `navigationBarItems`, and this button opens a new `sheet`, and the new sheet will pop up a window to ask user locations. However, in the new sheet, CLLocationManager() has been called twice, and location permission pop up window will disappear in a few seconds. When you create a regular button, the location pop up windown will be stay there until you select one of the options, and CLLocationManager() will only be called one time.

### Code

**ConentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {


    @State var show = false
    @State var showEditPage = false

    var body: some View {


        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Text")
                Button("Location button") {
                    print("Location button tapped")
                    self.show.toggle()
                }.sheet(isPresented: $show) {
                    NewPage()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(

                trailing:
                VStack {

                    Button(action: {
                        print("BarItemButton tapped")
                        self.showEditPage.toggle()
                    }) {
                        //Top right icon
                        Text("BarItemButton")
                    }.sheet(isPresented: $showEditPage) {
                        //Open sheet page
                        NewPage()
                    }

                }//End of trailing VStack
            )

        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**NewPage.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewPage: View {

    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var body: some View {

        Text("New Page")


    }
}

struct NewPage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewPage()
    }
}
```

**LocationManager.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        print("In LocationManger.swift @initi, this is called")
    }

    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    @Published var lastLocation: CLLocation? {
        willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
    }

}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.locationStatus = status

        print("In LocationManger.swift @Func locationManager, Status is updaing")

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        self.lastLocation = location
        print("Location is updating")

    }

}
```

### GitHub

You can feel free to download the project to try it on your laptop to see the issue:
[Github Example Project](https://github.com/skysf/SwiftUI-navigationBarItems-issue)

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please post your code instead of expecting people to download an Xcode project.

Comment: Hi @creeperspeak, updated text code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are changes of possible approach to make it work in your code:

1) Make LocationManager be only one

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    static var defaultManager: LocationManager = {
        LocationManager()
    }()
    ...
```

2) Use default manager instead of creating every time SwiftUI wants to create/copy view structure

```
struct NewPage: View {

    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager.defaultManager
    ...
```

Comment: Hi @Asperi, Thank you so much for your answer. It works well. I was busy with other project, so forgot to check this question. May I ask you why you come out this solution ? How come static would help this issue ? I don't really get the logic behind it. Pls feel free to share with us here, Thanks in advance.